# UNIQUE constraint failed sqlite

Tags: sqlite, constraints

Before I alter a table I want to make a backup of it, so I use this code :

```
CREATE TABLE states_BACKUP (
    state_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    domain VARCHAR(64), 
    entity_id VARCHAR(255), 
    state VARCHAR(255), 
    attributes TEXT, 
    event_id INTEGER, 
    last_changed DATETIME, 
    last_updated DATETIME, 
    created DATETIME, 
    context_id VARCHAR(36), 
    context_user_id VARCHAR(36), old_state_id INTEGER, 
    
    PRIMARY KEY (state_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(event_id) REFERENCES events (event_id)
);
INSERT into states_BACKUP
Select  * 
FROM STATES;
```

However when the insert part is executed an error message says :
Execution finished with errors.
Result: UNIQUE constraint failed: states_BACKUP.state_id
At line 18:
INSERT into states_BACKUP
Select  *
FROM STATES;

when I change the code to

```
Select distinct * 
FROM STATES;
```

I get the same eror.

Trying to find an answer on the web how to solve this problem, I find this error has to do with duplicate id's. I wonder how this can happen when I just copy a table.

Anyone has a solution for this ?

Comment: Does the original tabke have state_id marked as a primary key?

Comment: Replace your `*` with explicit column names and add explicit column names to the `INSERT INTO` statement too. **Never use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM` in production code** because you'll never know if you have mismatched columns.

Comment: @ OMSoP state_id  is marked as primary key indeed. I allready assumed that could be a problem, so for making a backup table it will not be a problem to lose that. But when I restore the data I am going to face the same problem I suppose, because than it has to be a primary key.
@DAI , you are right, but I don't think there is a great risk here

Comment: @justme I think the problem is that you have mismatched columns - that would explain why it's inserting duplicate values into the destination `state_id` column if it's mapped to a different source column.

Comment: @dai. I wouldn't know how that should happen. I use the code to create the table that is provided by DBbrowser to create the source table. Only changed the table name. The insert code is copied from the code to create the table. I did not type any field name or field-type myself.